# Overwrite Default CSS Style

Tags: css, html, wordpress

Back to basics, I have neglected my CSS skills thus my CSS is a bit (very) rusty I'm working on a wordpress theme. The style.css themes default H2 style is coded as follows:

```
h2 {
    font-size:1.7em;
    background:url(images/heading_bg.gif) repeat top;
    color: #fff;
    padding:6px;
    border-bottom:3px solid #e40001; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

This result in any `<h2>` tag inserted into a post looking like this:

[image]

This provides a nice look in the theme however in certain situations I would just like to have a basic unstyled `<h2>` tag thus I created the following class:

```
.normal{
font-size:1.4em;
font-weight:bold;
color="red";
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

**MY Problem - What I want to Achieve**

*I would like to overwrite the default `<h2>` style of the theme in certain situations however if I add the above class to any `<h2>` tag the .normal class is ignored and it keeps on displaying the normal h2 rule*....why is this? What am I missing? How can I overwrite the default h2 style at certain types?

Comment: You'll want to look into the CSS specificity rules. They dictate which styles are applied when there are conflicts like this.

Comment: Try to use `h2.noraml` instead of `.normal`.

Comment: @CollinD 'You'll want to look into the CSS specificity rules; Can you please expand I'm not quite getting you...?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Something like these https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity  or  https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @alirezasafian....nope did not work :(

Comment: For more infor pls visit https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: please check that your custom css file loads after your theme file is finish loading. It might can resolve your issue

Comment: Try my answer @alirezasafian

Comment: @Mohamed I didn't ask the question but `!important` is a bad practice.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Please, provide more information. Post your completed  code or provide a demo.

Comment: @alirezasafian Then pls provide ur full code info

Comment: @alirezasafian that is pretty much my full code...

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Put your default css link on top and then put your custom css file on below that. Apply this method and write the css styles.

Comment: @Mohamed I am not the person who asked the question. Do you understand?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee or else appy an id instead of a class

Comment: Can you post the link of your website?It is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: ID is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: `color="red";` should be `color: red;`

Answer (score 2):

This the snippet I worked out. Doesn't seems a problem to me. Go through this code carefully.

PS: `color="red";` is wrong. Use 
when you want to override some element, you gotta look at the rules used in that element. ie, you gotta remove the background if any, change margin, paddings etc.

```
color:red;
```

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOVzy.jpg) repeat top;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e40001;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.normal {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>
 hello
</h2>

<h2 class="normal">
  Hello World
</h2>
```

Comment: avoid using !important tag as much as possible. its a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

You should mention all css properties of `h2` in your `.normal` class, thus it will be something like this:

```
.normal {
    font-size:1.4em;
    background:none;
    color: #FF0000;
    padding:0px;
    border-bottom:none; 
    text-transform:initial;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: This is the only sane answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code:

```
h2.normal{
font-size:1.4em;
font-weight:bold;
color="red";
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

which means h2 has a class normal then overwrite the styling

Comment: Nope doesn't work sticks to default style, but thanks for answer

Comment: You may want to add css rules replacing the `padding` and `background` with non-stylized versions etc that are not being overwritten from the global rules.

Comment: make sure this css file is added below the inherited style of wordpress theme

Answer (score 1):

You may do one of these:

1. use `.normal` selector after `h2` in your css file (assuming they have same specificity)
2. use `!important` in your `.normal` decleration

   ```
   .normal{ propert: value !important; }
   ```
3. add some specifity to the `.normal` selector like:

   ```
   h2.normal{ bla bla ...}
   ```